# Right outer join with OR conditition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have below query -

```
select *  
from  g 
right outer JOIN  p
ON
( g.c1  = p.c1
or g.c2=p.c2
or g.c3=p.c3
)
```

OR condition in ON clause is causing serious performance issue.

I tried with UNION as -

```
select g.*,p.option_code  
from  g 
right outer JOIN p
ON (g.c1= p.c1)

UNION

select g.*,p.option_code  
from  g 
right outer JOIN p
ON (g.c2=p.c2)

UNION

select g.*,p.option_code  
from  g 
right outer JOIN p
ON (g.c3=p.c3)
```

IS it possible to realise this join in alternative way.

Best Regards

Comment: try union ,if you are still facing the issue,post explain

Comment: How do you know it is the OR that causes slow performance? That doesn't sound right. Did you run each of the three separate joins (with each condition by itself) and found all three to be fast, but the join with the OR condition is much slower? That would be pretty odd.

Comment: @TheGameiswar - how do you use union or union all to get the same result set as from outer join? Union will remove duplicates, and union all may introduce duplicates where none existed (for unmatched rows).

Comment: I tried with UNION operator. It gave me immediate output but output row count did not match.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: @mathguy . . . `or` in join conditions is often a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

First, `right outer join` is so hard to follow logically.  So, let's replace this with a `left join`:

```
select *  
from p left join
     g 
     on g.c1  = p.c1 or g.c2=p.c2 or g.c3 = p.c3;
```

Assuming you want the *first* value that matches, you can do something like:

```
select p.*, coalesce(g1.col, g2.col, g3.col)
from p left join
     g g1
     on g1.c1 = p.c1 left join
     g g2
     on g2.c2 = p.c2 left join
     g g3
     on g3.c3 = p.c3;
```

You can add as many `coalesce()` expressions as you need.

This is not 100% the same as your query, but it works in many similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct *
from 
(
select g.*,p.option_code  
from  g 
right outer JOIN p
ON (g.c1= p.c1)
UNION all 
select g.*,p.option_code  
from  g 
right outer JOIN p
ON (g.c2=p.c2)
UNION all
select g.*,p.option_code  
from  g 
right outer JOIN p
ON (g.c3=p.c3)
) x
```